# Difference between override and new when forcing override ToString() in C#

Tags: c#, overriding, tostring

I have this experimantal code:

```
interface I { string ToString(); }
class TestI : I {
    public override string ToString() { return "Hello"; } 
}

abstract class A1 { public override abstract string ToString(); }
class TestA1 : A1 {
    public override string ToString() { return "world!"; }
}

abstract class A2 { public new abstract string ToString(); }
class TestA2 : A2 {
    public override string ToString() { return "world!"; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TestI ti = new TestI();
        I i = ti;
        Console.WriteLine(ti); Console.WriteLine(i); //predictable writes "Hello"
        TestA1 ta1 = new TestA1();
        A1 a1 = ta1;
        Console.WriteLine(ta1); Console.WriteLine(a1); //predictable writes "world!"
        TestA2 ta2 = new TestA2();
        A2 a2 = ta2;
        Console.WriteLine(ta2); Console.WriteLine(a2); //writes "ConsoleApplication1.TestA2"
        Console.WriteLine(ta2.ToString()); Console.WriteLine(a2.ToString()); //good
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Why `new` keyword breaks method `ToString()` in the case #3?
I understand method `Console.Write` has a signature like `ToString(params object[])`, and it using `object.ToString()` realization.

In this case, how to force overriding `ToString()` correctly?
I don't whant to use case #4.

Comment: The *new* keyword suppresses a compiler warning that tells you that you are probably writing bad code.  Well, you did, you now also know what goes wrong.  You cannot force anybody to override ToString(), just stop trying that.

Comment: @HansPassant While most uses of new I have seen in practice are exactly the evil kind of uses you describe I would say that this is pretty narrow way to look at the usage of new. The purpose of that construct is not to stop compiler warnings.

Comment: @ApceH Hypocrite I don't get what you are trying to achieve. How is that you both want to override ToString and not want to override ToString (indicated by the usage of new)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to force people to override `ToString` why not just have a base implementation that calls an abstract method on your class. For example:

```
abstract class Base
{
  protected abstract string GetMessage();

  public sealed override string ToString()
  {
    return GetMessage();
  }
}

class Derived : Base
{
  protected override string GetMessage()
  {
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

Now you're not trying to trick the compiler and it will be clear to anyone using your classes what they have to do.

Comment: Thanks! This is like template method pattern. This is what i need!

Answer (score 0):

In case Console.WriteLine(a2); the compile time type of a2 inside the Console.WriteLine method is an object because the overload that takes an object is called. Since you have NOT overridden the ToString() method of object the default ToString() in object is called. You are not overriding ToString() on object because you broke the chain by hiding the method in the abstract class via the "new" keyword (used to hide a method of the parent class).